# rvest not pulling hyperlinks despite xpath input, unsure why?

Tags: r, rvest

I have been trying to scrape hyperlinks on the world bank's publication's website. I have been trying to get the links for either the PDFs or the TXT files on this website using `rvest` but to no avail.

Here is my code thus far using its xpath:

```
library(rvest)

# Function to extract all links from URL
download_link <- function(url) {
  page <- read_html(url) 
  download_link <- page %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '// [@id="docdetail"]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/p/span/a')
  return(download_link)
} 

url_sample <- 'https://documents.worldbank.org/en/publication/documents-reports/documentdetail/323431468249620613/haiti-emergency-recovery-and-disaster-management-project'
# the function does not seem to grab the link to the .txt file 
txt_link <- download_link(url_sample) 
txt_link
```

I was expecting since the xpath is highlighted correctly in html that the function would grab the link but the return on txt_link came up empty.

Any help on how to resolve this would be great!

Comment: If you view the HTML source for that page, you will see that the links to the TXT and PDF files are not contained in it. So this is one of those web pages with dynamic content generated by Javascript, which rvest cannot access. You'll have to try something like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html).

Comment: Don't scrape the page, use the [API](https://documents.worldbank.org/en/publication/documents-reports/api).  `jsonlite::read_json("https://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/wds?format=json&fl=*&guid=323431468249620613&apilang=en")$documents[[1]][c("pdfurl", "txturl")]`.

Comment: Hi Ritchie thanks for this I had no idea that the world bank has an API!